# How can I query a fire store sub-collection with angular?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query a Firestore sub collection in an ionic 4 app/angular app. My database looks as follows people(id) ----> tasks(id)

```
{ description : this is a description about a cat,<br>
  title: this is a cat <br>
  category: cat }
```

I am using a Firestore function to query all of the data in the collection. This is what the Firestore function looks like:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

admin.initializeApp()


    export const getFeed = functions.https.onCall(async (req,res) =>{
    const docs = await 
    admin.firestore().collection('people').limit(5).get()

    return docs.docs.map(doc => {
    return {
        postID: doc.id,
        ...doc.data()
       }
    })
 })
```

the typescript home.ts file looks like this :

```
    const getFeed = this.aff.httpsCallable('getFeed')
    this.posts = getFeed({}).subscribe(data=> {
      console.log(data)
      // this.posts = data
        })
    }
```

I've tried to use the array-contains option to query, but it doesn't 
work. The array shows up empty on the console.

```
   export const getFeed = functions.https.onCall(async (req,res) =>{
    const docs = await 
    admin.firestore().collection('people').where("category", 
    "array- 
    contains", "cat").limit(5).get()

    return docs.docs.map(doc => {
    return {
        postID: doc.id,
        ...doc.data()
       }
    })
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear from your question, but it looks like the `category` field of your database isn't actually a list type field.  `array-contains` only works if the value is a list, not if it's just a single string value.  If it's just a string, then use a `==` filter on it.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have tried the above solution but im still getting an empty array in the console. I've tried all these :    const docs = await admin.firestore().collection('people').where("category", "==", "cat").limit(5).get()
   // const docs = await admin.firestore().collection('tasks').where("category", "==", "cat").limit(5).get()
    //const docs = await admin.firestore().collection('people').where("tasks", "==", "cat").limit(5).get()
   still doesn't work sadly :(

Answer (score 0):

I have found workaround by adopting array field type instead of subcollection.

Here is an example of my code:

```
  var coll = this.firestore.collection('credentials', ref => ref.where('tags', 'array-contains-any', ['agile']).orderBy('shortName')); // selects part of collection where roomId = roomStripped, sorted by name
```

return coll.snapshotChanges();

I have main collection called credentials, and a list of tags in each document.